# After groupingby using groupby function and trying to print the dataframe, its missing the values in the column with which i grouped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am missing values in the column by which i grouped the dataframe
Here is the code

```
weather=[('01/01/2020','Rain',24),('02/01/2020','Sunny',38),
         ('03/01/2020','moderate',30),('04/01/2020','Rain',21),
         ('01/01/2020','Rain',24)]
df=pd.DataFrame(weather,columns=['date','climate','temperature'])
df
```

**This is the output before grouping**

```
date    climate temperature
0   01/01/2020  Rain    24
1   02/01/2020  Sunny   38
2   03/01/2020  moderate    30
3   04/01/2020  Rain    21
4   01/01/2020  Rain    24
```

**Applying groupby function**

```
g=df.groupby('temperature')
for temp,temperature_df in g:
    print(temp)
    print(temperature_df)
```

This is the output after applying groupby to the dataframe

```
21
        
 date climate temperature

3  04/01/2020    Rain         NaN

24
        
 date climate temperature

0  01/01/2020    Rain         NaN

4  01/01/2020    Rain         NaN

30
         
date   climate temperature

2  03/01/2020  moderate         NaN

38
         
date climate temperature

1  02/01/2020   Sunny  02/01/2020
```

As you can see, I am getting NaN as the value in temperature column.

Please advice

Comment: Can't replicate your problem with the example you gave?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `df.dtypes` command to see if the temperature values are numerical. If they are not numerical you can try using:

`df['temperature'] = pd.to_numeric(df['temperature'], errors='coerce')`.